# sql server executing update it takes more time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables (UserTable and UserProfile) and the Structure:

```
create table userTable(
id_user int identity(1,1) primary key , 
Name varchar(300) not null , 
Email varchar(500) not null , 
PasswordUser varchar(700) not null,
userType int ,
constraint usertype_fk foreign key(userType) REFERENCES userType(id_type)
on delete set null
)
```

and userPtrofile:

```
    create table UserProfile(
    id_profile int identity(1,1) primary key , 
    ClientCmpName varchar(300) null,
    Clientaddress varchar(500) null,
    phone varchar(50) null,
    descriptionClient varchar(400) null,
    img image null,
    messageClient text , 
    fk_user int ,
    constraint fkuser foreign key(fk_user) references userTable(id_user) 
    on delete cascade  
    )
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.
The problem is that when I update records the executing load without executing 
this is sample query:

```
update UserProfile set messageClient=N'010383772' where fk_user=2;
```

screenshot

[image]

Comment: I suspect part of the performance hit is that it's updating a `text` field which isn't stored inline with the rest of the row data and is an extra hop per record to update. However the documentation on this (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189574(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_0) says that as long as the data is small, it shouldn't have to do that extra hop. I don't know if this optimization was done for 2008 though.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is performance for this query:

```
update UserProfile
    set messageClient = N'010383772'
    where fk_user = 2;
```

Then an index will be very helpful:

```
create index idx_UserProfile_fkuser on UserProfile(fk_user);
```

This should make the query almost instantaneous.

Note:  indexes can slow down inserts and other operations.  This is usually not a big issue, and having indexes on foreign key columns is common.

Comment: thank you so much to quick the answer but my problem does not solve

Comment: Foreign keys are already non-clustered indexes so adding another index to it wouldn't bring a performance increase - as the OP has said.

Comment: i'm not sure where you get this information, but it is not true for SQL Server (it is true for MySQL, however):  "Unlike primary key constraints, when a foreign key constraint is defined for a table, an index is not created by default by SQL Server. " (https://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/benefits-indexing-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, why are you trying to do an update based on a `[userType]` value ?

```
update UserProfile set messageClient=N'010383772' where fk_user=2;
```

Don't you want to update this value on one specific `[UserProfile]` based on its ID (which is a Primary Key, so would be much faster)

```
UPDATE [UserProfile] 
SET [messageClient]='010383772' 
WHERE id_profile=2;
```

Perhaps the performance problem is due to your UPDATE attempting to update all of your `[UserProfile]` records with this particular `UserType` value...?

Or I'm missing the point of what you're trying to do (and how many records you're attempting to update).

Comment: i have only one recored

Comment: Okay, and how is performance is you run my UPDATE, with a particular [UserProfile] ID value ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have alredy started a transaction (BEGIN TRANSACTION) on the table in another process (maybe another query editor page) and until you don't stop that transaction the table would not be available for updates. 
Check the variable select @@trancount, or try do rollback the updates you have already made (ROLLBACK TRANSACTION).
Also check if other tables can be update without issues.

Comment: i check for other table it is ok and update was success

Comment: if i helped you in some way, please check the answer as accepted, just below the arrows, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the query ever executed? It rather seems like a deadlock. You should 
[open the activity monoitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TrTk.png) and [check if your query is blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGgHw.png) by some process.

In that case, you should kill the blocking query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to help me
my problem fixed  the problem was another query editor page because i worked with asp.net and another page i use the same record to update the same record when i stop the asp.net project then query was success